# What are some useful tools for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm fairly new to Objective C, but have had some experience with Java. In Java tools like JUnit and JDocs can be extremely useful. Do these tools have parallels within Objective C, or are there even more useful tools for Objective C? At the moment I'm using X-Code and the iOS simulator.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure what JUnit and JDocs are as I have zero Java experience but Xcode itself has a ton of useful documentation and unit testing features. There is also UIAutomation, and Instruments build into Xcode/Mac

Comment: Yeah, from what I've seen so far, X-Code is a really useful IDE, I just have to learn more of its features. JDoc is a open database that works to combine everyone's Java classes to form a giant API. So far I've been able to use the apple developer pages to get a lot of this information. JUnit is a quick testing IDE supplement that lets you test your code quickly and effectively using what are essentially beefed up boolean statements, that doesn't make you go through the interface of your actual application. Does XCode have a feature that lets you test your app without running the iOS Sim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

Most useful are all the resources in developer.apple.com. They have docs, examples, references etc.

Also, use the Instruments app to help debug, analyse, and monitor your app. The various 'Instruments' therein are very useful.

For unit testing, you can include these when creating your app as standard (by simply checking the appropriate box). OCUnit is included. You can also try Google Toolbox, GHUnit, CATCH and OCMock to supplement this.

If I think of anything else, I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks! I'm starting to think that the Apple Developer site will have most of the JDoc equivalent data. Does Apple allow independent developers to submit their own methods and associated documentation? I've looked into a few additional libraries to add to my code, and think before this project is over I'll likely need to find a few more.

Comment: No Apple doesn't allow 3rd parties to submit their methods and docs. Many independents keep their own docs etc and use github, bitbucket, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find about unit testing here.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/00-About_Unit_Testing/about.html

For acceptance testing, KIF (Keep It Functional) from Square is a good option. KIF can simulate buttons clicks and text entries.
https://github.com/square/KIF/

Instruments is really useful tool to debug memory issues.  Leaks and Allocations tools have been very useful.  You can see who is retaining and releasing a particular objects in Allocation tools, which is useful in finding out retain-cycles.  If you work with codes before ARC, 'zombie' tool is invaluable as well.

Static Analyzer in XCode can quickly point out some potential issues.
XCode--> Product --> Analyze

Other than Apple excellent documentation, you can also watch WWDC videos.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/